# Ajax process PHP form with different results from multiple conditionals

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I've currently got a working form right now that just uses a conditional to check if it's been submitted and processes the form on the same page: https://gist.github.com/adrianrodriguez/48cd90067a63691adc6a

But obviously the caveat is that it refreshes the page. Which in reality is fine, I just used a little bit of JS to fadeIN the results after the form echos it with

```
style="display:none"
```

And that's sorta fine...but I want to spice it up and use ajax.

Below is the js without ajax (just using validation.js for validating)

JS **UPDATED WITH ANSWER**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Jquery Form Functions
    $('#redeem').validate( { // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            fullname: {
                required: true
            },
            cardnumber: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            email: {
                email: true,
                required: true
            },
            confirmation: {
                email: true,
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#email"
            }
        },
        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var message = "<p>All fields in red must be filled*</p>";
                $("#redeem .message").html(message);
                $("#redeem .message").show();
                } else {
                    $("#redeem .message").hide();
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                //form.submit();

              $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                dataType: "json", // Recognize JSON Data
                success: function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        // Loop with key and value from conditional
                        console.log(key + " " + value); 
                    });
                }
              });
              return false;
            }
        });

    if ($('.result')) {
        $('.result').fadeIn(400);
    }
});
```

I know how to process with ajax using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.action,
    type: form.method,
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
return false;
```

And it works fine, but the problem I run into is when I want to echo specific strings based on some of the conditionals in the form.

A) I can't echo the information out since the form is separate from the page it's processed on...

B)...and I don't know how to pull in that information to the current page it's being processed on.

Is this even possible? If so, how? Or do I just need to stay with what I have going on now?

Here is a video of what I have working now (without ajax): http://screencast.com/t/196P9ugso2L and notice how if a page is long it won't feel like the form is being processed real time (instead of refresh). Like I said, in all honestly, I just want to give a better user experience and spice things up.

**UPDATE**

PHP with array (which I think I am doing wrong, I tried three different ways, all failing noob style).

```
    <?php

include('db-connect.php');

$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$cardnumber = $_POST['cardnumber'];

$select = "SELECT * FROM cardholders WHERE cardnumber = $cardnumber";

$selectfrom = mysql_query($select);

if ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectfrom)) {

    if ($fullname == $info['name'] && $info['used'] == 0) {

        // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        // $headers .= 'CC: $email' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: Comanche Nation Casinos <no-reply@comanchenationcasinos.com>';

        $confirmation = '<h1>Hi ' . $info['name'] . ' you\'ve won <b>$' . $info['amount'] . '</b> in Comanche Credit!</h1>
        <p>Thank you for being such a valuable C Club member. Print or Show this email and redeem this at your Comanche Nation Casino.</p>
        <p>Save this email just incase something happens so that the staff can ensure your reward at the kiosk.</p>';

        // mail("web@icgadv.com", "Care Center Gala Sponsorship Request", $staff, $headers);
        // mail($email, "Care Center Gala Sponsorship Request Confirmation", $confirmation, $headers);

        // $message = "<p>Congratulations!" . $info['name'] . "!</p> <p>You've won! Please check your email for your winnings and futher information.</p>";
        $winner = true;

        $message = array( 'winner' => true, 'message' => 'This is a test');

        $updateUser = "UPDATE cardholders SET email='$email', used=1 WHERE cardnumber = $cardnumber";

        $update = mysql_query($updateUser);

    } else if ($fullname != $info['name'] && $info['used'] == 0) {

        // $message = "Sorry but your name does not match the name in our database.";
        $noname = true;
        $message = array( 'winner' => true, 'message' => 'This is a test');

    } else {

        // $string = "<p>Sorry but this offer has already been redeemed to this account</p>";
        $redeemed = true;
        $message = array( 'winner' => true, 'message' => 'This is a test');

    }

    } else {
    // $message = array( 'status' => true, 'message' => "<p>Sorry but this card number    does not exist.</p>" );
    $invalid = true;
    $message = array( 'winner' => true, 'message' => 'This is a test');
    }

    echo json_encode($message);
?>
```

Comment: If you're using Ajax why is the form on a separate page it's processed on? I read that as you submit the data to a page then make an Ajax call on the page you just submitted the data to, am I right?

Comment: @Styphon, I'm not sure I understand your question. When I tried to process the form via ajax with the form being on the same page it failed. With previous projects my forms were always separated from the page it was processed on and worked fine. ***(without this feature I am asking for)***

Comment: OK, I understand now. @TomToms answer is, although lacking detail, what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @TomToms posted above the problem is you need to pass a result back from the Ajax page called, the one processing. As mentioned, you do this using a JSON array. I will give you a brief example of this below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: form.action,
    type: form.method,
    data: $(form).serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Note the added dataType, this states you are expecting a JSON string back, and will convert it into an array in `data` for you.

On you processing page, the `form.action` you would have this:

```
// ... code that loads form information and all your current processing.
$example = array(
    'prize'    => true, // true or false on whether they get the prize.
    'status'   => 'Show Status Message' // put any message for the show status box here.
);

echo json_encode($example);
```

Now if you look in console at the end `data` will be an object with the prize and status in it.

I'd also recommend you have a look through the [JSON website](http://json.org/) for more information on JSON.

Comment: Does it have to be an array? Could it just be $string = 'String'; echo json_encode($string); ?

Comment: `json_encode($string)` would just produce `String`. Whilst you can do it, there is no point. The whole point of json_encode is to turn an array into a string. You have two areas you need to update, you can't update both with a single string, hence why you need JSON.

Comment: thanks for dealing with me so far, and please continue to excuse my inexperience here with JSON. I read the documentation and then some other PHP to JSON threads, and have tried a few things with no results. I'm wondering if I am just doing this wrong. Do I need to convert my conditionals into an array and then echo the message using json_encode?

Comment: Yes, that is what you will need to do. If you are still struggling after doing that, update your original question with the code in your Ajax page and I will help you further.

Comment: I've updated the original question, I think my biggest hurdle is figuring out how to turn my conditionals into an array.

Comment: What you've got should work. When you look in the console does the winner and message come up as expected?

Comment: No, It sends the form fine, but I've got nothing showing in the console.

Comment: dataType is not necessary anymore since jQuery 1.4 a JSON response will yield a JavaScript object based on MIME and anyways I would have wrote it dataType: "json".

Comment: @adrianrodriguez Without being at your PC it's going to be hard to diagnose exactly what the problem is. You're going to need to learn to use the console. If using Chrome you will have a network tab, make sure that you are making the Ajax call and then start var dumping stuff on your ajax page and viewing the result on the network tab to make sure you get what you expect. Just do debugging through your code until you find the problem.

Comment: @Styphon thanks for all your help. That's definitely what I've been doing this whole time. :) Hope I haven't disrupted anything you guys have been working on. I will try and figure this out and if I can't get it, I will just deal with it. Haha. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Styphon After removing the dataType and then adding this code: `$.each(data, function(key, value) {console.log(key + " " + value);});` I actually get some errors in the console: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '41' in {"winner":true,"message":"This is a test"} **

Comment: I've got it! I just looked up the error and it said it wasn't recognizing it because it didn't know it was JSON. So I added with @Tom Toms mentioned `dataType: "json",` and voila, it worked! Thanks for all your help guys. I will update my question with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly what you need is to send back a JSON array with a status code for each field or something along those lines and then parse that in your javascript to warn the user appropriately.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more, with some possible code examples? I've not touched JSON before and could use some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

[As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), `.ajax()` always goes inside of the `submitHandler` callback function.

Replace this...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {  // fires on submit when form is valid  
    form.submit();  // regular submit action
}
```

With something like this...

```
submitHandler: function (form) {  // fires on submit when form is valid 
    $.ajax({
        url: $(form).action,
        type: $(form).method,
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;  // block the default form action
}
```